# Convert VARBINARY to Base64 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base64, data-conversion

This seems like a basic scenario, but I can't find relevant info anywhere.
I'm new to MySQL, coming from years of Microsoft SQL Server experience.

In MySQL, how do you convert a `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` value into a Base64 string, and vice-versa?

In Microsoft SQL Server, I've been using code like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[convert_binary_base64] ( @input [VARBINARY] ( 3000 ) )
RETURNS [VARCHAR] ( 4000 ) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST ( '' AS [XML] ).value ( 'xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@input"))' , 'VARCHAR(4000)' ) ;
END
GO
```

According to `mysql.com`, it looks like the `TO_BASE64` function only converts from text to text:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64

As with the Microsoft SQL Server example above, is there an XML or JSON operation available in MySQL to perform this action?

Or can I force MySQL to "interpret" a `VARBINARY` variable as text, and pass the text to `TO_BASE64`?
(And if so, would that cause a performance degradation?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To_BASE64 can also use VARCHAR as base and insert into varchar

```
DELIMITER //
 
CREATE FUNCTION encodebase64(
    Inputtext 
    VARBINARY(3000)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 Return TO_BASE64(Inputtext);
END //
 
DELIMITER ;
```

So that

```
 SELECT encodebase64('text');
```

returns

```
# encodebase64('text')
dGV4dA==
```

Comment: This makes no diffence, simply change the input and test it-. I updated the answer

Comment: Which Mysql version. 8.018 runs ok.

Comment: Yes You have to copy all the code inclusive the DELIMITER at the beginning and End

Comment: Right, I _kindof_ understand, but I ended up getting it to work by removing the `DELIMITER` and removing `BEGIN` and `END`. Last question: How do you perform the reverse operation then? Decoding the Base64 text back into `BINARY` or `VARBINARY`?

Comment: exchamge  input and outpu and change the fuction  FROM_BASE64(Inputtext) and you will get binary code. mysql shows blob. And please remove the downvote